# XCODE 4 to 4.2 differences when calculate etc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, xcode4.2

After migrating from XCODE 4 to 4.2 i have quite a few problems with my applications, many of them due to my own bad code quality.

As an example i had for some reason done two calculations looking like:

> xx = xx++

...which worked in XCODE 4 but not in 4.2 where the compiler jumped over and did not either process or warned about it. This took me a week to find&fix even if i tried to read-up on the differences between 4 and 4.2.

Changed it to:

> xx++

..so it works now :-)

However, i still have problems so i wonder if someone could point me to where i can read about these type of "smaller but important" differences, which hopefully can help me track the other issues down.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of undefined behaviour. These sorts of changes are not often documented, because they only occur when you break your contract with the compiler.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/367633/485561) (it is related to C++, but there are a lot of common undefined behaviours between C++ and Objective-C) for some more examples.